# Why am I unable to use the prop only once in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

So I am looping through an array and passing each iteration to a React Hook. In this react hook component I am displaying a bootstrap card that is working correctly. Also on this card has a button that opens a modal that displays more information about the prop object that is currently being used for the card. When the button is clicked it opens the modal but the modal will only ever contain information about the first iteration. All the cards display correctly with each iteration, but the modal does not.

```
export const ProductCard = (props) => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const product = props.product;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productTitle = product.title;
  const productReviews = product.reviews;

  return (
    <>
      <Card className="product-card">
        <div className="image">
          <Card.Img
            className="product-img d-block mx-auto"
            variant="top"
            src={product.image}
          />
          <div className="image-overlay">
            <Button
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#productModal"
              className="cart-button"
              style={buttonStyle}
            >
              quick shop
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Card.Body className="text-center">
          <Link
            to="/"
            className="body-link"
            style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
          ></Link>
          <Card.Title className="card-title">{title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text className="card-text-rating">{rating}</Card.Text>
          <Card.Text className="card-text-price">${product.price}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="container">
        {console.log(product.title)}
        <div
          className="modal left fade"
          id="productModal"
          tabIndex=""
          role="dialog"
          aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div className="modal-dialog product-modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content product-modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header quickshop-modal-header">
                <p className="quickshop-title">Quick View</p>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="close quickshop-close"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body product-modal-body">
                <p className="quickshop-product-title">{title}</p>
                <img
                  src={product.image}
                  alt="product-img"
                  className="quickshop-product-image"
                />
                <hr className="line-break" />
                <div className="quickshop-price-container">
                  <p className="quickshop-price-title">Price:</p>
                  <p className="quickshop-price-number">${product.price}</p>
                </div>
                <hr className="line-break quickshop-linebreak" />
                <hr className="line-break quickshop-linebreak" />
                <div
                  className="quickshop-add-product"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#productAddedModal"
                >
                  <p className="quickshop-add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</p>
                  <IoCartOutline className="quickshop-cart-icon" />
                </div>
                <div
                  className="quickshop-add-wishlist"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#productAddedModal"
                >
                  <p className="quickshop-add-to-wishlist">ADD TO WISH LIST</p>
                  <HiOutlineHeart className="quickshop-wishlist-icon" />
                </div>
                <Link
                  style={viewDetailsStyle}
                  to="/"
                  className="quickshop-view-all-details"
                >
                  View All Details
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have removed all the functionality of this component. I can log each iteration and it will log each one so it is iterating through the array correctly. I am unsure why when opening any modal it only displays the first iteration information.

As requested here is the component that I am looping through the array

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ProductCard } from "../Product-Card/ProductCard";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { product } from "../../actions/products";

import "./ProductList.css";

export const ProductList = () => {
  // const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(product());
  }, []);

  const filteredProductsList = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productReducer.filteredData
  );
  return (
    <div className="product-list-container">
      <Container>
        <Row xs={2} md={3} lg={4}>
          {filteredProductsList.map((product) => {
            return (
              <Col key={product._id}>
                <ProductCard product={product} />
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: please post how are you looping trough. The real problem might be how you are looping, not the modal. Pease post the hook and the iteration part too

Comment: I have attached where I am looping through the array